# Laravel Scout & Algolia - can't create index on staging server after migrating from TNTSearch to Algolia

Tags: laravel-5.3, algolia, staging, laravel-scout

this is very weird. I've successfully created an index on my local server and it showed up in Algolia dashbord.

However, when I ran `php artisan scout:import 'App\MyModel'` on my staging server I get:

```
Imported [App\MyModel] models up to ID: 22
All [App\MyModel] records have been imported.
```

but the index doesn't show up in Algolia dashboard.

I've compared my `.env` files and these fields are the same on both of my apps:

```
SCOUT_DRIVER=algolia
SCOUT_PREFIX=staging_ //this one is "development_" on my local server 
ALGOLIA_APP_ID=aaaaa
ALGOLIA_MONITORING_KEY=bbbbb
ALGOLIA_SEARCH=ccccc
ALGOLIA_SECRET=ddddd
```

my `config/scout.php`

```
'driver' => env('SCOUT_DRIVER', 'algolia'),
'prefix' => env('SCOUT_PREFIX', ''),
'queue' => true,
'algolia' => [
    'id' => env('ALGOLIA_APP_ID', ''),
    'secret' => env('ALGOLIA_SECRET', ''),
],
```

and here is my `config/algolia.php`

```
'default' => 'main',
'connections' => [

    'main' => [
        'id' => env('ALGOLIA_APP_ID'),
        'key' => env('ALGOLIA_SECRET'),
    ],
    'alternative' => [
        'id' => 'your-application-id',
        'key' => 'your-api-key',
    ],

],
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

It seems that index file `my_models.index` in the `storage` folder gets updated when I run `php artisan scout:import 'App\MyModel'`

I believe this is a leftover from using TNTSearch before Algolia but I can't figure out why is my app using TNTSearch and not Algolia one on my staging server.

I concluded this because when I run `php artisan scout:import 'App\MyModel'` this index file gets updated on my staging server but not on my local machine.

**UPDATE #2**

ssh into server, inside of `php artisan tinker` I get `algolia` if I run `env('SCOUT_DRIVER')` or `config('scout.driver')`.

**UPDATE #3**

Tried the `php artisan config:clear` and `cache:clear` but I still get new `my_model.index` file after I run the `scout:import` on my model.
Even after I've deleted all mention of TNT from `.env`, `composer.json` and `AppServiceProvider.php`.

Comment: OK, this is a bit of an awkward situation, but probably the best course of action: we don't want "[solved]" in the question, there is an answer, and the problem is hence not really reproducible, but this whole thing may still help somebody in the future… I've undeleted your "answer" so you can accept it, rolled back your question edit and closed it too. You can now accept your answer to put this to rest.

Comment: I know this sounds like a silly mistake but I think that something went wrong (probably a feature, not a bug thing) with caching on my server. I don't think this should be deleted. I lost a day trying to figure it out and only restarted the server out of despair. This is not Windows XP and restarting a server after installing a new PHP library shouldn't be (and isn't) something you're expected to do. Right thing to do would be to find out why this happened but sadly I don't have the time nor the expertise to do it.

Comment: Well, if you can ever expand this answer to something more in-depth, I'd agree that it's a worthwhile problem with a solution. As such… "restarting it" should be one of the default troubleshooting steps methinks. Anyway, this question won't be deleted, it'll just stay closed until further notice.

Comment: Hm, ok I wont be lazy and will sent the email to Laravel and DigitalOcean. Hope something comes up from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restarting the server fixed it!